# HDP: Gibbs sampler implementation

Tags: text-mining, hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs, dirichlet-process

I am trying to recreate the model proposed by [Gao et al. (2011)](http://cgcad.thss.tsinghua.edu.cn/shixia/publications/topicmergesplit/paper.pdf), based on the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process proposed by [Teh and al. (2005)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf).

To estimate the model (let's call it iHDP) I need to implement a Gibbs sampler as described in Section 5.3 in Teh et al. (2005). I think I understand all the elements of this process, apart from estimating the probability of an assignment to a new cluster - Eq. 37 in Teh and al. (2005), repeated in Eq. 9 in Gao et al. (2011).

By analogy to Gibbs sampler for LDA I think I know how to compute $f_k^{-x_{ij}}(x_{ij})$ - from a posterior of the $k$-th topic, using its term counts. But how do I calculate $f_{k_{new}}^{-x_{ij}}(x_{ij})$? Teh and al. (2005) write:

> $f^{−x_{ji}}_{k_{new}}(xji) = \int f(x_{ji}|\phi)h(\phi)d\phi$ is
>   simply the prior density of $x_{ji}$.

while Gao et al. (2011) write:

> $f^{−x_{ji}}_{k_{new}}(x_{ji}) = p(x_{ij})$

It seems to me that this is just the probability of getting whatever the term in $x_{ij}$ is. Suppose I'm using a symmetric Dirichlet distribution as a base distribution for the topics, would that mean that mean that $f^{−x_{ji}}_{k_{new}}(x_{ji})$ is just $\frac{1}{|V|}$ where $|V|$ is the size of the vocabulary? It doesn't seem very intuitive, especially because the superscript $-x_{ij}$ is said to mean "considering all other observations".

Could someone perhaps offer some intuition behind this, or correct my reasoning if it's wrong?